# Where is the distinction between a web application and an API?

Tags: django, api, design-patterns, web-applications

This question is highly related to [this over question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203205/distinction-between-api-and-frontend-backend). I'm asking another question between I still am a bit confused on the topic.

### The Issue I Ran Into

I currently have a Django web application where users can have a list of their hobbies and can increment a counter each time they do one of their hobbies. My issue is, I want to extend this functionality outside of a front-end experience. In other words, I want users to be able to increment their hobbies using a `POST` request, say, from the terminal or from their own script or something.

### Where I'm Confused

**Do I have to create an API for my webapp to add this functionality?**

Another way to put is, do I have to handle requests coming from the front-end differently than requests coming from somewhere else? Would front-end requests go to the URL `www.hostname.com/hobbies/1` and other requests go to the URL `www.hostname.com/api/hobbies/1`?

If I do route the `POST` requests to the same URL as the requests coming from the front end (i.e. `www.hostname.com/hobbies/1`), then how come google has [external APIs for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation)? It seems like if other web applications are calling Google Maps functionality then Google has separated those instances from their front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is, I want to extend this functionality outside of a
>   front-end experience. In other words, I want users to be able to
>   increment their hobbies using a POST request, say, from the terminal
>   or from their own script or something.
>
> Do I have to create an API for my webapp to add this functionality?

Most likely yes. There are several reasons for this:

1) A `POST` request from a terminal/script will most likely fail against your `/hobbies/1/` endpoint, because of Django's [CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf). You need a different type of [authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#authentication) and [authorization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#permissions) for requests outside of your application.

2) A `POST` request from a terminal/script will most likely have it's content encoded as `JSON`, while a `POST` request submitted via html form will have it's content encoded as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. This requires completely different type of validation and error handling as a response which lead us to 3).

3) A `POST` request against your `/hobbies/1/` endpoint will most likely return a HTML response, which is not what your terminal/script would want to receive, they will most likely want to receive a more structured type of data, such as JSON.

Combining solutions for 1) + 2) + 3) will give you `/api/hobbies/1/`.

Comment: Is the only reason to separate the two because of the POST request? In order to accomplish this, it seems like the only change that is happening is to my service layer? I would simply keep the business logic and everything the same, then add an additional component to the service layer that handles API calls, and this component would call the same business logic as the front end service layer component?

Comment: Its not only because of POST request. If you read 1) and 2) again you will see that you have the same problems with GET requests too. API views are completely different kind of beast, why do you want to complicate things instead of keeping them simple? Business logic does not belong to views anyway, it need to stay inside the models where it will be reused by either Django Views or API views.